# How can I format date column in SQL table to be in US format

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry but very new to SQL and was wondering how I create my table date column so the date format is in US mm-dd-YY currently my table presents in YY-mm-dd

I'm currently using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `User_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `parent_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_phone` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `experience` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dob`, '%m-%d-%Y') AS `formatted_date` FROM `users`;
```

Comment: Your date is stored internally the same, no matter what locale you use. But you can output it differently with `date_format`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you can use `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dob`, '%m-%d-%Y') AS `formatted_date` FROM `table`;
```

Comment: I've updated my question with your line of code, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use the DATE_FORMAT(date,format) function to format to whatever format you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

You can not change that

The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`.

The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

However you can use the function `DATE_FORMAT()` to format the date while running the query or using some server side functions like PHP [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime) you can get the date the way you want.